# How to export data from multiple tables to csv from remote postgres server (AWS RDS) to local machine?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, export

I need to export data in CSV format from many (undertimined amount) tables from a remote postgres (**aws RDS PostgreSQL 10.6**) server to a local machine.

When the server was in its own machine (AWS EC2) this was possible with a function that used a loop to iterate over the necesary tables then used **execute** and **COPY** commands to create the CSV files directly onto the same server from which they could by copied over where needed.

But since the server was migrated to an RDS instance, I can't use that approach anymore because I have no direct access to the filesystem on the postgres server. I can only connect to it remotely via a client.

Every solution I've seen until now requires either filesystem access to the server or works with only one set of data at time with a known table that produces only one csv file on the local machine.

Is there a way to achieve what I need ?

Comment: You can write a query to generate `\copy` commands to run in `psql`. Check the documentation about the difference between the `copy` statement (which exports to the server's filesystem) and the `\copy` command in `psql` (which exports to the client's filesystem).

Comment: @colin-t-hart I know about `\copy`, but that is only recognized from the psql client so it can't be inside a query, so no dynamic/multiple table or file names.

Comment: I'm not saying run it directly, but to *generate* the statements which you will then run in psql.

Answer (score -1):

if it was on premises, only thing you need to is to mount it first and then and run this as a sql query :

```
DO $$
DECLARE ssql varchar := 'COPY ( SELECT  * from schema.table1   ) TO ''/projeler2/Raporlar/SatisRaporlari/test' 
|| TO_CHAR(NOW(),'DD_MM_YYYY') 
|| '.csv'' WITH CSV DELIMITER '','' HEADER QUOTE ''"''  ;';

BEGIN
    EXECUTE ssql;
    --raise notice 'Value: %', ssql;
END; $$;
```

but remote server may change the game. give it a try